# Custom Rewrite with Query vars

Tags: permalinks, rewrite-rules, query-variable

I have been stuck on this for hours and tried all these different methods but none seem to work. I've seen other threads with a similar problem but the solutions are not working for me. I'm hoping someone can help.

I have a page with a custom template using the permalink

```
example.com/central
```

This page accepts query variables eg :

```
example.com/central/?information=people
```

I'm trying to get a custom rewrite rule to work so that when people type in

```
example.com/central/information/people
```

it will display what

```
example.com/central/?information=people
```

does.

currently in my template functions.php I have

```
function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ){
  $vars[] = "information";
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );

function custom_rewrite_tag() {
  add_rewrite_tag('%information%', '([^&]+)');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);

function custom_rewrite()
{
        add_rewrite_rule('^(.+)/information/(.+)/?$','index.php?p=64476&information=$matches[2]','top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite');
```

When I visit

```
example.com/central/information/people
```

I only get taken to

```
example.com/central/
```

My second issue is that p=64476 is hard coded, how do I get the id from $matches[1] ?

Answer (score 3):

[Add a rewrite endpoint](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint) instead of a rewrite rule and query var. This API function will do both of these things for you.

```
function wpd_add_my_endpoint(){
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'information', EP_PAGES );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpd_add_my_endpoint' );
```

Now any page can have `information` appended to the end, and the value will be available via `get_query_var('information')`.

Comment: Hi Thanks for that, rewrite endpoint looks like a much better way to go. however I'm still getting a 404 error.

I tried changing EP_PAGES to EP_PERMALINK but that didnt work also. Any ideas?

Comment: did you flush rewrite rules after changing them?

Comment: Hi, I did a flush by visiting the permalinks setting page in the back end. Is there another way to flush the rules or how can I test the end point is enabled?

Comment: how to do the appended thing??? add_query_var doesn't seem working....

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I did a quick test and it worked for me. I created a page called `central`.

*Don't forget to flush the rewrite rules after inserting this code.*

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'information_query_vars' );
function information_query_vars( $vars )
{
    array_push($vars, 'information');
    return $vars;
}

add_action( 'rewrite_rules_array', 'information_rewrite_rules' );
function information_rewrite_rules( $rules )
{
    $newrules = array();
    $newrules[ 'central/information/people/?$' ] = 'index.php?pagename=central&information=people';

    return $newrules + $rules;
}
```