# add_rewrite_rule doesn't work for me

Tags: rewrite-rules

I'm trying to use add_rewrite_rule to make custom URL.
My problem is the same as here : [Custom Rewrite with Query vars](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/189168/custom-rewrite-with-query-vars)

But I tried the 2 solutions, and it doesn't work for me.

For testing, I installed locally a new version of wordpress with default theme Twenty fifteen. I installed the plugin Rewrite rules Inspector to see all the active rules.
I added a page "test" and added this function in function.php :

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'query_vars' );
function query_vars( $vars )
{
    array_push($vars, 'information');
    return $vars;
}

add_action( 'rewrite_rules_array', 'rewrite_rules' );
function rewrite_rules( $rules )
{
    $newrules = array();
    $newrules[ 'test/information/people/?$' ] = 'index.php?pagename=test&information=people';

    return $newrules + $rules;
}
```

I don't forget to flush the new rules.

But when I go to :
index.php?pagename=test&information=people

wordpress write the url :
?pagename=test&information=people

and not :
test/information/people/

Why ? What's wrong ?
It seems that Wordpress has a rule over mine.
I don't understand ...Help !

Answer (score 0):

You've got it the wrong way round - WordPress won't rewrite (redirect) your query string (known as canonicalization), but it *will* pass your parameters through if you use the rewritten URL:

```
http://example.com/test/information/people
```

Now if you `print_r( $wp-query_vars )` in your template, you should get something like:

```
Array
(
    [pagename] => test
    [information] => people
)
```

To redirect params to the "pretty" (rewritten) URL, [take a look at `redirect_canonical`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/redirect_canonical/)

Comment: Ok, I understand. I find this : add_filter('redirect_canonical','my_redirects',10,2);
`code`
function my_redirects($redirect_url, $requested_url) {
 // do stuff
 return $redirect_url;
}
`code`
But I don't know how can I write this. 
I tried to change .htaccess too. It is a wrong way too ?