# Setting custom canonical urls

Tags: php, functions, customization, rel-canonical

I have a page that requests and displays information from a database. All is fine but I'm having some trouble setting custom canonical URLs for this single page only and its URLs (with parameters inside).

Example:

https://example.com/primary-page

https://example.com/primary-page?requested_id=1

https://example.com/primary-page?requested_id=2

https://example.com/primary-page?requested_id=3 and so on...

These links with "?requested_id=id" automatically inherit the same canonical link as the "primary-page". Which I would like to modify in order for these links to have their own and full URLs as canonical link.

I've been looking for a solution for a few days now without luck. I hope one of you will be able to help me, which I do not doubt at all.

So, thank you so much in advance!

Comment: I'd research here on WPSE for adding custom rewrites to map, for example, `https://example.com/primary-page/request/2` to `https://example.com/primary-page?requested_id=2`.  Then the canonical URLs ought to just come out in the wash.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how your canonical URLs are being written to the page. In your theme's header you may find something like:

`<link rel="canonical" href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">`

If you are able to edit your theme (or child theme if using a distributed theme) you can put whatever you want there instead. For instance, you could put:

`<link rel="canonical" href="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">`

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] includes all of the query parameters.

(Or if you are using a plugin like Yoast, it will add the canonical link to your page for you. You should be able to filter this output. With Yoast, it is the "wpseo_canonical" filter.)

But remember, in many cases it makes sense to not include the query parameters, for instance two pages that vary only in a ?sortby= parameter do in fact share duplicate content, and the whole point of canonical tags is to help identify duplicate content.

It might make more sense to add your parameter as a query arg and give it a rewrite rule, so that it becomes part of the more standard URL and is included by default. Instead of `primary-page?requested_id=1` it could be `primary-page/1`. It also looks a little better.

If you want to do that, there are a couple of different answers on [this related question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/189168/custom-rewrite-with-query-vars).